# Will two estimators converge to the same answer?

Tags: estimation, unbiased-estimator

Say I have two estimators for the same quantity and using the same model, $E[f(X)]$. I also know that these two estimators are consistent, meaning, if we have a lot of data, they will be close to the true $E[f(X)]$ -- but all of this under the assumption that the model is *correct*! MLE is one kind of estimator like this.

Will they converge to identical answers even if the model is not correct (i.e. the i.i.d. samples are not sampled from the parametric family of the model)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question. I believe that the answer depends on every single element of the problem: the true model, the estimators employed, ...

An extreme example is: let $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ be an independent sample where $x_j\sim \text{Cauchy}(0,1)$ and define the estimators $\hat{\theta}_1=\text{mean}(x)$ and $\hat{\theta}_2=\text{median}(x)$. Now, suppose that you thought that those observations came from a Normal distribution $N(\mu,1)$ and that you are interested on estimating $\mu$. Under these assumptions $\hat{\theta}_1\stackrel{a.s.}{\rightarrow} \mu$ by the Law of large numbers and $\hat{\theta}_2\stackrel{a.s.}{\rightarrow} \mu$ by Glivenko-Cantelli Theorem.

However, considering the true generating model, since the mean of the Cauchy distribution does not exist $\hat{\theta}_1$ behaves erratically (given that its limit does not exist) while $\hat{\theta}_2$ still converges to $0$ (since Glivenko-Cantelli still applies).